# Google drive Query with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

I would like to query (using Python) the list of files from a specific folder in google drive. I have used the following code. It returns the file list for all the files for all folders but I am not able to get the list for a specific folder. Can someone help? Thanks!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
file_service = DRIVE.files()
files = file_service.list().execute().get('files', [])
for f in files:
file_shared = (file_service.get(fileId=f['id'], fields="name, 
shared").execute())

# Only display files that are shared
if file_shared['shared']:
    print(file_shared['name'], f['id'])
    #for f in file_shared:
    #   print('title: %s, id: %s' % (f['title'], f['id']))

# Sleep 1/10 of a second between every API call, otherwise
# you will exceed the number of calls allowed
time.sleep(.100)
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, when you want to retrieve a file list in the specific folder, how about modifying from ``files = file_service.list().execute().get('files', [])`` to ``files = file_service.list(q="'### folderId ###' in parents").execute().get('files', [])``? The document of query is https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Comment: Wow! it works like magic! Thanks a lot Tanaike!! Trying to upvote/ accept your solution..not finding..

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved. And thank you for your concern. I posted it. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification point:

- In order to retrieve a file list in the specific folder, please use `q` for `file_service.list()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
files = file_service.list().execute().get('files', [])
```

To:

```
files = file_service.list(q="'### folderId ###' in parents").execute().get('files', [])
```

- `### folderId ###` is the folder ID.

#### Reference:

- [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters)